# No output in the file created in this program

Tags: java, web-services, rest

This is my first Web service. I wanted to send some parameters to this service and I want the web service to save the data into a file in text format. 
The file is created, but it is EMPTY.

```
package com.first.jersey.tutorial.latlng.resources;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/values")
public class Parameters {
String path="hi.txt";

@GET
@Path("/{param1}/{param2}")
public void makeFile(@PathParam("param1")double a,@PathParam("param2")double b){
    try {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileWriter w=new FileWriter(path);
        w.write("{\"Latitude\":"+a+",\"Longitude\":"+b+"}");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
}
```

I used the following URL to run this program.
http://localhost:8080/latlng/webapi/values/17/80
I use this code and I expected a file to be created with {"Latitude":17,"Longitude":80} JSON format. I want to use these variables to update the location marker in my Google Maps web application using AJAX.

The location latlng variables should be sent by an android application to the web service in URL. So, every time when the application sends data, the file should be updated replacing the previous data with current location data.

I don't know if this is the easiest way for fulfilling my requirement. If there is any other way so that my code will be a bit tidy, please suggest me that code.

Comment: "Is this a valid code?" Does it compile?

Comment: Thats probably his follow up question

Comment: it will be stored in `@Path("/{param1}/{param2}")`

Comment: Have you considered just running it and finding out?

Comment: @tnw - not a good idea.   The problem is that if you treat this as a "black-box" you can come to the wrong conclusion

Comment: @StephenC Eh? I'm just suggesting that OP run the code to find out if it works and if there's even a problem before posting here. If it doesn't then they'll at least have a valid question for SO if they included details about *how* it doesnt work. If it works and they're still looking for critique, they could very easily post it on code review.

Comment: I posted this here because It got compiled and I tried to run it. I got no error any where and I got no output either. That is the reason I posted it here. May be the question format is wrong. But it still remained as a question. You people are just trying to make fun out of it. Why don't you give me a straight answer? You might not have probably read that this is my first web service. I expected some kind of help. Sorry. @tnw

Comment: @Prasad We *are* trying to help you. If you read the comments, we're obviously asking what the actual problem is here. Presumably you posted here because there's some sort of issue with it but you never told us what it was. You should update your question with what your inputs, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. I hope you can understand our confusion.

Comment: @tnw. I updated my question. If you can find the required data. Please answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

> ... where will the file be created?

Indeterminate.  It depends on the "current directory" of the web container / appserver.  That depends on how it is launched.

Using a relative pathname in a web application is probably a bad idea.  (At least, in production code.)

**UPDATE**

The most likely reason that the file is being created empty is that you don't flush or close the file after writing it.

Comment: Sir. Now the question is edited. If you can get that, please help me. Anyways, thanks for coming forward to solve my problem.